# UPS Multiple sync connections

Tags: user-profile-service

I have a scenario where I want to push the SharePoint profile pictures to AD.  I have this down and all is good in a test environment.

In my production environment I want to start pushing this out.  However I only want to do it to a certain group for the time being.

My question is:  If I have more than one sync connection (my normal one then another that exports a picture for a certain people set) will one orverride and wipe out the other?

I've tried this in my Dev environment but just want to make sure that I won't overwrite anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is yes... the export will "export" for all valid profiles, so it would override or "null" out photos if they aren't in SharePoint. The simple workaround would be to add filters to the export sync connection so that only profiles within a specific OU (or some other criteria) are included in the export sync.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this webdes03.  Your solution worked.  Thank you.